# Logger not logging on Deployer Extension (CD)

Tags: content-delivery, logging, deployer-extension

I'm creating a new PageDeploy extension and I'm not seeing any logs created. I know that my class is being called since if I create an exception I see it in cd_X_conf.xml, but if no exception is thrown, nothing is logged.

I'm creating my extension like this:

```
package com.my.tridion.deployer.extensions;

<IMPORTS REMOVED>

public class PageDeployExtensionModule extends com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy
        implements IModuleCallable {

    private IModuleCaller moduleCaller = null;

    private static Logger logger = null;

    public PageDeployExtensionModule(Configuration config, Processor processor) throws ConfigurationException {
        super(config, processor);

        this.moduleCaller = new ModuleCaller ();
        logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PageDeployExtensionModule.class);

        logger.debug("JUST TO SEE IN LOGS");
    }

@Override
public void processPage(Page page, File pageFile) throws ProcessingException {
    logger.debug("PageDeployExtensionModule.processPage --> Processing Page ID: " + page.getId().toString());
    super.processPage(page, pageFile);
}
```

In logback.xml I have created the following entry:

```
<logger name="com.my.tridion.deployer.extensions">
    <appender-ref ref="rollingDeployerLog"/>
</logger>
```

In cd_deployer_conf.xml I've modify the PageDeploy module with this:

```
<Module Type="PageDeploy" Class="com.my.tridion.deployer.extensions.PageDeployExtensionModule">
```

I've restarted deployer service and nothing.

I see the logs being created but my entries are not there. Any idea?

Thanks in advance. Guillermo.

Comment: What is the log level in logback.config.

Comment: It is debug Hiren

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you added this in your logback.xml:

```
<root level="DEBUG">
   <appender-ref ref="rollingDeployerLog"/>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks! That along with adding the package to logback.xml made it worked.

Comment: Glad that it worked :)